# Design UITableView background image

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I want to use a background image for a tableview.

I use the following code to present the image (in viewDidLoad):

```
    tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

    let bgView: UIImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "tableview-bg.png"))
    tableView.backgroundView?.addSubview(bgView)
```

I designed images in the following sizes (px):

```
480×320,
960×640,
1136×640,
1334×750,
2208×1242
```

I named them (respectively):

```
tableview-bg.png,
tableview-bg@2x.png,
tableview-bg-568h@2x.png,
tableview-bg-667h@2x.png,
tableview-bg@3x.png
```

I copied them into my Images.xcassets folder but still don't see the background.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your tableView background color clear color and insert image view behind that

Comment: That's exactly what I did, didn't I?

Comment: you are adding imageView on tableView instead of doing that, add that to main view before adding tableView in code or in storyboard keep it behind tableview

Answer (score 2):

you add the imageview as a subview to the background view which is nil in this moment. instead assign your imageview to be the backgroundview:

```
tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

let bgView = UIImageView(frame: tableView.bounds)
bgView.image = UIImage(named: "tableview-bg")
tableView.backgroundView = bgView
```

Comment: Additionally, I don't think the imageNamed call can resolve anything but scale decorators on the name. So tableview-bg-568h@2x.png and tableview-bg-667h@2x.png won't get automatically used.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the bgView inside your viewController's view and then bring tableview to front with clear color like this:

```
tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
let bgView: UIImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "tableview-bg.png"))
self.view.addSubview(bgView)
self.view.bringSubviewToFront(tableView)
```

Make sure your tableview's cells are also having a clear color background in order to see the image

Comment: problem is that large title doesn't collapse properly when embedded in navigation controller

Answer (score -2):

Make sure you copy your images to Bundle Resources.

Click the game name at the tap of the screen and then click "Build phases"  and then click "copy bundle resources" and pick your images.

[Click here to see the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vpuc2.png)